# how many possible clients and subscription possible im mosiquitto broker

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

how many clients and subscription is possible in mosquito broker. which runs on amazon ec2 t2 micro. What is maximum subscription possible . If there how to overcome it

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to answer without knowing all of the following (and more):

- The size of messages you are sending
- The rate of messages you are sending
- The QoS of the subscriptions
- How many retained messages you will be storing
- Will you be queuing messages for offline clients

You are going to have to test any set up you intend to use with production style loads.

Out of the box, the most likely first limiting factor you will hit is going to be the default ulimit setting for the number of open file handles a process can have. This defaults to 1024 as a soft limit and 4096 as a hard limit.

Comment: Add to that: number of subscribers, subscriber performance, topic hierarchy, distribution of topics, network architecture, ... Like you say: too many variables to answer in theory.

Comment: how can i test the load

Comment: Have you investigated load testing tools?